# How are third-party providers (e.g. Huawei) supposed to unintentionally take over control of their products?

Tags: networking, security, isp, internet-security, telecommunication

In Germany, it was/is being discussed whether telecommunications providers must replace hardware and software from Chinese companies such as Huawei.

The reason given is that the foreign companies could, for example, record data traffic or disable ISPs' network elements through their management software.
But what surprises me: The management software and user data are used in the ISPs' internal networks. In other words, in networks that are not accessible to the public. (Similar to how nobody (should have) access to your home network)

So how is supposedly malicious software supposed to be able to cause damage here if you can regulate exactly which data traffic is routed where and thus, for example, only allow connections from the management software to desired servers and block everything else?

In addition to the technical aspect, there are of course also economic sanctions, that is for sure, but I am more interested in how it is technically possible to "break out" of controlled networks.

I probably don't have a good enough insight.
I would therefore be interested to hear what experts think about this topic and whether the fears of politicians are really true from a technical point of view.

Comment: "in networks that are not accessible to the public", "you can regulate exactly which data traffic is routed where" – What hardware or software separates networks? With what hardware of software do you regulate? What if it may be the hardware and software in question?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
Good thoughts, but Juniper or Cisco devices or whitebox/open source alternatives are mainly used for routing etc.. 
Other manufacturers (F5, Fortinet...) are used as a firewall, so no Huawei devices. I know this from work (I'm a trainee at an ISP, but don't know anyone who can answer this question for me).

Comment: "so no Huawei devices" – How do you know? *Maybe* the point is to enforce this, among other areas. Another thing is: how would Cisco/whatever know if some SSH communication is not a Chinese router "phoning home"? The network may be "not accessible to the public", but if a rogue agent is already inside and able to initiate communication with the outside then this will be a backdoor.

Comment: The issue at play here is the Chinese government maintains control over businesses in China and full access to user data, networks, and devices, of which is why western countries want Huawei equipment out of critical infrastructure. This is equally why the US HoR just passed a bill to ban TikTok from US app stores.

Comment: There's probably a political aspect here - Huawei's military linked, and their pricing was *very* attractive, even loss leading. Banning for security reasons is likely 'easier' to jusitify than "our local telephony companies can't compete"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how is supposedly malicious software supposed to be able to cause damage here if you can regulate exactly which data traffic is routed where and thus, for example, only allow connections from the management software to desired servers and block everything else?

This is 100% speculation. But:

- Much more often, what makes networks "not accessible to public" is not route-ability but rather packet filtering; a firewall that drops packets from "outside" *after* they got routed (with routing being mostly indiscriminate). So a router or firewall that provides packet filtering could, very easily, have invisible rules that still allow packets from certain IP addresses – or with [certain criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit) – despite external access being seemingly blocked.

  (Indeed most home wifi routers already have quite a few of those – both for internal purposes, and often a few for management by ISP. And of course those have been exploited in the past, e.g. certain router models accidentally leaving UPnP IGD "port forwarding" controls reachable from the WAN side – the router just has a checkbox "[✔] Enable UPnP", it doesn't tell you that it has added a firewall rule to make it work, and you usually can't inspect what kind of rule it has added.)

  At some point in time, we used to have a HP ProCurve switch that needed to have a public IP address – it was at the very edge of the network, outside any of our firewalls (and our parent org wanted it to be pingable for their monitoring), but like most such devices do, it had its own built-in feature to limit access to certain IP addresses only. We found out the hard way that 1) no matter what netmask you entered, it would "round up" to a whole octet and allow access from the entire /24; and 2) sometimes after adding a new IP entry it would start ignoring the list completely and allow access from everywhere until reboot.
- Often, the mechanism that legitimate admins use to access their networks is some kind of VPN (software or appliance), and there have been *many* bugs and sometimes even backdoors in VPN systems allowing unwanted access in the past – e.g. just recently it was a bug in [F5 BIG-IP](https://www.theregister.com/2024/03/22/china_f5_connectwise_unc5174/), and mere weeks before that it was a bug in [Ivanti PulseSecure](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/01/mass-exploitation-of-ivanti-vpns-is-infecting-networks-around-the-globe/) that's still making news articles, etc.

  You can't always tell whether bugs are accidental or not, but sometimes you find obviously deliberate backdoors, like [the Juniper one](https://www.csoonline.com/article/554095/the-juniper-vpn-backdoor-buggy-code-with-a-dose-of-shady-nsa-crypto.html), or the [Barracuda one](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/01/secret-backdoors-found-in-firewall-vpn-gear-from-barracuda-networks/), etc. (Not to mention all the discoveries of NSA tampering with Cisco hardware, back in 2015 or so...)

So from the technical side, if you are a network equipment manufacturer then it's very easy to sneak in something that allows you to bypass your regulations (the more of your products someone uses, the more opportunities you have) – which means, depending on which country your product is developed in (not only China but also e.g. UK's "investigatory powers" laws come to mind), it's also very easy to be *forced to* sneak in something like that.

---

Add-on that goes with point #1: Sometimes, the *hardware* may be made to react to certain packets before they even reach the normal packet filtering. Several practical examples that come to mind:

- The "baseboard management controllers" found on many servers, e.g. branded "iLO" or "iDRAC". The BMC is an always-on, separate computer running inside the server that has its own IP address, can power-on the server, capture its screen, etc. (very useful but also very much a security risk by its nature, and again you can't really tell what kind of backdoors it has).

  BMCs almost always have a "shared NIC" mode where they use a special feature in the server's built-in NIC to Y-split traffic depending on MAC address, so you only need one Ethernet port to connect both devices – hopefully using VLANs for separation, but many people forget or don't even realize that their server has a BMC and just let it grab a public address via DHCP.
- Intel AMT, a remote management feature found in some business PCs. Much like BMCs, it's an always-on component that lets you power the system on/off remotely, except it's *part of the CPU* (and relies on the built-in Ethernet port), and it's even more evil in the way it does networking: it will literally snoop on the host system's DHCP packets to learn what IP address you've got, and then it will divert packets *for a single TCP port* to itself.

  That means, if you get the IP address 192.168.1.7 for example, then a TCP connection made to 192.168.1.7 port 16992 never reaches your OS – it goes straight into the CPU's AMT; which means it cannot be filtered by Linux iptables or Windows Firewall on the OS.
- Optical network connections use SFP modules to allow the optics to be swappable on demand – you can plug in a module for SMF, a module for MMF, a module for copper RJ45, a DAC cable... Most SFP modules are pretty basic, just signal conversion, but e.g. there are modules for GPON or VDSL that have quite a bit of logic in them – you can fit practically a whole GPON ONT, with its own IP address and configuration, in there.

  So of course there are [products like this](https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/post/smart-sfp-linux-inside) "Smart SFP" that runs Linux and has built-in features for diverting certain packets. This one is quite large and if you get it from your "regular SFP" order it obviously has something going on, but you kind of get the idea.

Comment: There were some *really* wierd stories floating around of rice sized mini implants disguised as resistors and backdoors (which were plausible). That said, there are probably more straightforward and easy methods of industrial espionage

Comment: Rice-sized – I doubt it. But something the size of a PS/Xbox jailbreak mod is much more plausible, it's not like anyone is going to open up every single of their 20 brand new delivered routers...

Comment: https://archive.is/n3X0v source I read it from I honestly would take it would a very large grain of salt. [Krebs](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2018/10/supply-chain-security-is-the-whole-enchilada-but-whos-willing-to-pay-for-it/) seems to think its fake and most orgs involved deny it. Its bond villan level convoluted IMO

Comment: Would this answer apply to cellular antennas? For example, concerns with telecommunications antennas and equipment from Chinese companies is the Chinese govt by law having unfettered access to SMS/MMS messages _(which aren't encrypted)_, the [SS7 network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_System_No._7) underpinning the global telecommunications network - access to the SS7 network allows listening in on virtually any call, including politicians' _(a real world demonstration was even shown on a PBS investigation of the SS7 network, using a consenting US Congressman/Senator's cell)_, etc.

Comment: @JW0914: I've never worked with that kind of equipment, but I would not rule it out, as AFAIK they're a bit more than just dumb antennas but more along the capability of a WiFi AP. Since they're exposed devices – they have to talk to cell phones by nature – so *technically* I'd assume that there's nothing stopping a backdoor command from being added, that could be sent from a nearby cell phone to start capturing specific traffic or whatever. (Again mostly thinking about "how would I backdoor a WiFi AP?") Whether that's *realistic* and worth worrying anything more than politics, I have no idea.

Comment: @JW0914: On the other hand, though, what I've heard about SS7 security is roughly like BGP security, i.e. mitigation depends on the operator to a certain extent – i.e. I've heard that it's overall bad because everyone just assumed it'd never be publicly accessible, but still doubt that it's "virtually any call worldwide", more likely "these operators that handle most of USA traffic are exceptionally bad at applying mitigations".